# How to make a nametag with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

In Pygame, I'm attempting to create a nametag that appears on top of a rectangle. But I'm not sure how to center it properly. I've done a lot of research on how to fix this problem but haven't been able to find any posts or solutions, so I'd really appreciate it if someone could assist me with this.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

run = True

pygame.init()
    
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Mob Fighting Game")

vel_x = 2.5

vel_y = 10

isJump = False
Color = (255,255,255)

font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 15)

class Mob():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Name = name
        self.Character = None
    def CreateMob(self, xPos, yPos, width, height): 
        if not self.Character:
            self.Character = pygame.rect.Rect(xPos, yPos, width, height)
            return self.Character
        else:
            raise AssertionError("Character already exists!")
        
    def DrawMob(self):
        if self.Character:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.Character)

class Player():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Name = name
        self.Character = None
        
    def CreateCharacter(self, xPos, yPos, width, height): 
        if not self.Character:
            self.Character = pygame.rect.Rect(xPos, yPos, width, height)
            return self.Character
        else:
            raise AssertionError("Character already exists!")
      
    def DrawCharacter(self, DrawWithDisplay):
        if self.Character:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.Character)
        if DrawWithDisplay:
            DisplayNameText=font.render(str(self.Name), 1, Color)
            win.blit(DisplayNameText, (self.Character.left, self.Character.top))
        
Plr = Player("Jimmmy")
Chr = Plr.CreateCharacter(200, 200, 25, 25)
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
         Chr.move_ip(vel_x, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        Chr.move_ip(-vel_x, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        isJump = True
    if isJump:
        Chr.move_ip(0, -vel_y)
        vel_y -= 1
        if vel_y < -10:
            isJump = False
            vel_y = 10
    win.fill((0, 99, 0))
    Plr.DrawCharacter(True)
    pygame.display.update() 

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the rectangle with the size of the text and set the bottom center of the rectangle with the top center of the player (see [`pygame.Surface.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_rect)):

```py
text_rect = DisplayNameText.get_rect(midbottom = self.Character.midtop)
win.blit(DisplayNameText, text_rect)
```

[image]

---

Player class:

```py
class Player():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.Name = name
        self.Character = None
        
    def CreateCharacter(self, xPos, yPos, width, height): 
        if not self.Character:
            self.Character = pygame.rect.Rect(xPos, yPos, width, height)
            return self.Character
        else:
            raise AssertionError("Character already exists!")
      
    def DrawCharacter(self, DrawWithDisplay):
        if self.Character:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.Character)
        if DrawWithDisplay:
            DisplayNameText=font.render(str(self.Name), 1, Color)
            text_rect = DisplayNameText.get_rect(bottomleft = self.Character.topleft)
            win.blit(DisplayNameText, text_rect)
```